# The parametric equations for the motion of a projectile $ x = (v_0 \cos(\theta))~t$ and $y = h+ (v_0 \sin(\theta))~t-16t^2$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

The parametric equations for the motion of a projectile

$$ x = (v_0 \cos(\theta))~t$$

$$y = h+ (v_0 \sin(\theta))~t-16t^2$$

can be rewritten in rectangular coordinates as :

$$ y = \frac{- x^2 16 \sec^2(\theta)}{v_0^2}+ \tan(\theta)~x+h $$

The path of a projectile is given by the rectangular equation
$y = 6 + x − 0.08x^2$.

(a) Find the values of $h,~ v_0,$ and $\theta$. Then write a set of parametric equations that model the path. (Use the given formulas to write the equations. Enter your answers as a comma-separated list of equations.)

I'm not sure how to do a), but I already graphed it and found the max height to $9.13 $ and the range to be $16.93 $ feet.

Answer (score 0):

I think you made a slight mistake in either simplification or typesetting. You should get $$y=-\frac{16\sec^2\theta x^2}{v_0^2}+\tan \theta x +h$$

Now it should be simple to match each coefficient. The constant term, $h=6$. The coefficient of $x$ is $\tan \theta=1$. The coefficient of $x^2$ is $-16\sec^2\theta/v_0^2 = -0.08$. That should give you $h, v_0, \theta$.

Comment: Could you show how to find v0 and θ?

Comment: $\tan\theta=1$, do you know of any angle whose tangent is 1? Once you get $\theta$, finding $v_0$ is just a matter of rearranging the last condition (which we got from the coefficient of $x^2$)

Comment: pi/4, then v0 = 20, so x=(20cos45)t, y=6+(20sin45)t-165^2

Comment: x=(20cos45)t, y=6+(20sin45)t-16t^2 isn't the right answer either, what did you get?

Comment: I got that answer too! Are you entering this in an online auto-graded system? They are often very particular about the specific format of entry. It could be something as small as not putting brackets after writing 'sin', or maybe you need to simplify to decimals, or something like that.